# Unable to export Access DB table

Tags: database, ms-access

I have an access db and am looking to export the tables to csv.
All tables except one can be exported but one table gives me the error:

Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object". Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: It would be helpful in diagnosing if you indicated *how* you are exporting to CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I might of got round this by creating a query selecting the fields that I needed then exporting the query...

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to try is to do a compact and repair.  However make a copy of the database file first.   If that doesn't help then for more information on corruption including possible causes, determining the offending PC, retrieving your data, links, official MS KB articles and a list of vendors who state they can fix corruption see the [Microsoft Access Corruption FAQ](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/corruptmdbs.htm).